# Amazon S3 Mobile Uploading: creates bucket, won't upload image

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-s3

I've been working on this problem for quite some time now with no luck.  I am using the Amazon S3 iOS upload SDK as per http://aws.amazon.com/articles/3002109349624271

**Symptoms:**
Can create a bucket, will not upload image.  `S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];` returning nil.

**Here is my code:**
In viewDidLoad

```
self.s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
self.s3.endpoint = [AmazonEndpoints s3Endpoint:US_WEST_2];
```

Tried with and without endpoint; added as per https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=427879&#427879

In upload function called later in same view controller:

```
...
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.9);
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Upload image data.  Remember to set the content type.
        S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:PICTURE_NAME
                                                                 inBucket:PICTURE_BUCKET];
        por.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
        por.data = data;
        por.delegate = self;

        // Put the image data into the specified s3 bucket and object.
        S3PutObjectResponse *putObjectResponse = [self.s3 putObject:por];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            if(putObjectResponse.error != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", putObjectResponse.error);
                [self showAlertMessage:[putObjectResponse.error.userInfo objectForKey:@"message"] withTitle:@"Upload Error"];
            }
        });


        NSLog(@"image PUT to amazon");
        // Set the content type so that the browser will treat the URL as an image.
        S3ResponseHeaderOverrides *override = [[S3ResponseHeaderOverrides alloc] init];
        override.contentType = @"image/jpeg";

        // Request a pre-signed URL to picture that has been uploaded.
        S3GetPreSignedURLRequest *gpsur = [[S3GetPreSignedURLRequest alloc] init];
        gpsur.key                     = PICTURE_NAME;
        gpsur.bucket                  = PICTURE_BUCKET;
        gpsur.expires                 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval) 7200]; // Added an hour's worth of seconds to the current time.
        gpsur.responseHeaderOverrides = override;

        // Get the URL
        NSError *error;
        NSURL *url = [self.s3 getPreSignedURL:gpsur error:&error];

        NSString *imageURL = url.absoluteString;
        NSLog(@"%@",imageURL);
    });
```

Error is never thrown, and if I go to the URL it simply says "The specified key does not exist."

If you have any ideas, please let me know!  This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you set the bucket policy to allow you to upload objects?

Comment: Haha yes I have upload/delete permissions allowed.  Unless there is some step I don't know about; in the S3 Manager I allowed my account permission to upload/delete.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue yet? I'm having the same problem as well.

Comment: I was able to get around it, but I don't remember how unfortunately. (this was in an abandoned project)  Good luck and if I can find anything on it I will let you know!